# Irregular Font names in When combined with bold and Italic?

Tags: ios, ipad, uifont

I am developing an 'application forms filling' app and I create the forms by using the xml.

In the xml if I find a tags like below I will add the UIlabels as subView

```
<label x="" y="" width="" height="" text="First Name" textcolor="" font="Arial" Bold="NO" Italic="NO" .../>
<label x="" y="" width="" height="" text="Last Name" textcolor="" font="TimesNewRoman" Bold="NO" Italic="NO" .../>
```

It will look like

[image]

I use the same approach for UIButtons,sliders,UItextFields etc
(**Note**:-As much as UI Objects are created dynamically as much as tag I came across)

And My problem is applying font to them,
For example In the first tag I receive the font name Arial so If I create font using method

```
   NSString *fontName;
  //......getting font name from attribute 'font'.....
  [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:20];
```

Clearly the desired font can't be set as the name of the normal arial font is **ArialMT**

Inorder to overcome this problem I have to append MT at the end,But if I append so then I will get trapped in the second tag which is '**TimesNewRoman**' and the normal font of TimesNewRoman is **TimesNewRomanPSMT**.

My problem become further worsened If I get YES to Bold and Italics

For example If it is TimesNewRoman- 'PS' is suffixed with 'TimesNewRoman' and 'MT' comes after the hyphen in the font names.

```
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT
TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT
TimesNewRomanPSMT
```

If it is Arial the members are

```
Arial-BoldItalicMT
Arial-BoldMT
Arial-ItalicMT
ArialMT
```

Besides this In some fonts the use the term 'Oblique' is used instead of Italic as below

Font Family:- Courier

```
Courier
Courier-Bold
Courier-BoldOblique
Courier-Oblique
```

Is there any remedy to seperate the required fonttname from the family of fonts // No need to worry about name of the font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts do not have a bold, italic or oblique property. The font has to be designed with bold or with italic.

You could create an object to manage your fonts.  It would accept a base font name and you could add the bold or italic properties.  As an example:

```
FontPicker *fontPicker = [FontPicker alloc] init];

fontPicker.fontName = @"Helvetica";
fontPicker.bold = YES;
fontPicker.italic = YES;
fontPicker.size = 17;

UIFont *font = [fontPicker font];
```

This would return @"Helvetica-BoldOblique".  You will need to manage which font is actually picked based on the base font name and the attributes.

I can think of two ways to implement this.  One would just be to hard cord each base font and each property:

```
- (UIFont *)font
{
    if ([_fontName isEqualToString:@"Helvetica"]) {
        if (_bold && _italic) {
            return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:_size];
        }
        if (_bold) {
            return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:_size];
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could get a list of all the fonts for a family, and then check the names for Bold, Oblique, W6

```
NSArray *array = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:_fontName];
for (NSString *name in array) {
    if (name contains Bold or W6 or Black or Wide after the the "-") {
        Create the font
    }
}
```

Some fonts may not follow a standard naming (if there is one) so you would have to handle them special.

Comment: 2nd option I did not feel good as there are nearly 40 font families so I plan to implement First one, and your plan of creating a picker class is cool.